# How to generate numbers as multiples of 10s in particular manner?

Tags: javascript

How to generate numbers in the following pattern in js?

```
const output = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000, ... ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution. Basically you loop through the numbers 1-9 again and again, multiplying by 1, 10, 100 etc.

```js
const maxExponent = 5;
let exponent = 0;
let result = [];

while (exponent <= maxExponent) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        result.push(i * Math.pow(10, exponent));
    }
    exponent++;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the logarithm of 10 and add one to the found digit.

```js
const
    fn = i => {
        const l = Math.floor(Math.log10(i)),
              d = i / 10 ** l;
        return (d + 1) * 10 ** l;
        
    };

for (i = 1; i < 10000; i = fn(i)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A non math approach

```js
const
    fn = i => +i.toString().replace(/./, d => +d + 1);

for (i = 1; i < 10000; i = fn(i)) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not actually Math but working using string.repeat :)

```js
    max_zeros = 5;
    cur_zeros = 0;
    zero_string = '0';
    output = [];

    for (var cur_zeros = 0; cur_zeros <= max_zeros; cur_zeros++) {
    
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            output.push( parseInt(i + zero_string.repeat(cur_zeros)) )
        }   
    
    }
    console.log(output)
```

Comment: Very similar code structure to my answer (except mine uses math), and posted 1 second later!

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) which provide infinity number collection generation without rounding and string manipulation.

```js
  function* createGenerator() {
    let num = 1;
    let power = 0;
    while (true) {
      yield num * Math.pow(10, power);
      num += 1;
      if (num === 10) {
        num = 1;
        power += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  const num = createGenerator();
  let i = 30;
  while (i-- > 0) {
    console.log(num.next().value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With modular arithmetic and powers of ten:

```
function generateTens(n) {
    let ret = []
    for(let i=0; i<n; ++i)
        ret.push((i%9+1) * Math.pow(10, parseInt((i+i/9)/10)) )
    return ret;
}

console.log(generateTens(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another generator solution. Combined with `setInterval`, and bigint data type, it can just keep running as long as memory allows for it:

```js
function* gen(start=1n) {
    let next = start * 10n;
    for (let i = start; i < next; i += start) yield i;
    yield* gen(next);
}

let iter = gen();
setInterval(() => console.log(`${iter.next().value}`), 100);
```